# GeoPandas plot function not working

Tags: python, pandas, geopandas

I have a shapefile that looks like this on mapshaper: [image: mapshaper]

But when I tried to plot it in pandas with the following code

```
police = gpd.read_file('srilanka_policestations')
police.plot()
```

jupyter notebook gives me an error message saying "**AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'type'**".

I'm not sure what's wrong. I tried to plot the GeoPandas dataset "naturalearth_cities", and it works fine. See below:

[image: jupyter notebook]

The geo-dataframe reads fine in pandas, but it wouldn't plot: 
[image]

Any help is much, much appreciated. Thank you all!

Comment: HI, what is the output of `police.dtypes`?   And also what is the output of `type(police.loc[0,'geometry'])`

Comment: Does `police.geometry` works?
also try to add the file format, e.g. 'serilanka_policestations.shp'.

Comment: Thank you both! Bob, the output of `police.dtypes` is object for everything (including geometry). Latitude and Longitude are both float64. The output of `type(police.loc[0,'geometry'])` is string.

Comment: Alireza, `police.geometry` doesn't work either, and neither does adding a ".shp" after the file name. :(

Comment: `type(police.loc[0,'geometry'])` shouldn't be string, but should be a shapely.geometry.Point type. So something went wrong with reading that file. Are you able to share the shapefile? And you can also open an issue at https://github.com/geopandas/geopandas/

Comment: As a workaround, you can do `police['geometry'] = police['geometry'].apply(shapely.wkt.loads)` (to convert the strings to actual geometry objects)

Comment: Thank you for the link and the code, joris, I'll give it a shot soon. I tried to upload my shapefile, but I don't see where to do that on stack overflow. Will keep this thread posted on how my future attempts work out. In the meantime, I managed to make the map I need using folium!

Comment: Joris, I gave the line `police['geometry'] = police['geometry'].apply(shapely.wkt.loads)` a shot and it worked like magic. If you can post it as a solution, I'll go ahead and accept it — not sure how to do that in the comments section. Thank you so much once again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The geometry column in a geopandas GeoDataFrame should not contain strings, but actual geometry objects. 
If you have strings, you can convert them as follows:

```
import shapely.wkt
police['geometry'] = police['geometry'].apply(shapely.wkt.loads)
```

However, I have to say that the above is a workaround, as if you used geopandas `read_file` to read a shapefile, you should not end up with strings.